# Getting tail cmd output in python 2.7 using subprocess

Tags: python, linux, bash, python-2.7, subprocess

I am trying to tail a file's content through python. The code I am using is as below

```
#! /usr/bin/python

import subprocess
import os.path

# Get the file path
filepath = os.path.join(baseDir,"filename.*" + uniqueId)
# Call subprocess and get last 10 lines from file
spTailFile = subprocess.Popen(["tail", "-10", filepath ], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
tailOutput = spTailFile.communicate()[0]
print tailOutput
```

The above code throws an error as below:

```
tail: cannot open `/hostname/user/app/filename.*39102'
```

I see output if I execute the tail command with the filepath directly in bash.

```
tail -10 /hostname/user/app/filename.*39102
```

Why is subprocess passing an extra backtick (`) when executing the tail command?

**Update:**

I ended up using glob to find the file as @cdarke had suggested and then passing it to the Popen cmd.

Comment: Another possibility:  use Python function `glob.glob("filename.*")` to get a list of filenames.  Another possibility:  add `shell=True` to your `Popen` parameters, since it is the shell that does filename expansion (globbing).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bash extends the '*', Popen not.

Two possibilities:.
1. Do it within your script and pass a filename without '*'.
2. Create a Bash script and call this from python.

Comment: you were right, Bash was expanding the '*' which was causing the problem in tail. After passing in the full filename, the cmd executed as expected.